# React - Import Components from select/dropdown

Tags: reactjs, select, import, components, dropdown

I want to import and show a Component, depending on what you choose from a form, select.
I've got the select to work if you output the value, but how do I import a component and output it?

I have a useState with comp, setComp which get a value from the select, so that works.
But then what, how do I get this part to work..

```
 if(value==="xxxx"){
    import("./xxxx.js")
    setComponent(value)
} else if(value==="yyyy"){
    import("./yyyy.js")
    setComponent(value)
}
```

}

A bit further down in the code from the original form-tag I want to output my selected component.

Answer (score 0):

> 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level

if you try to render a component with a conditional rendering you need to do something like this:

```js
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      {true ? <Xxxx /> : null}
    </div>
  );
}
```

if want to import the component at run time you probably want to use lazy load..
see [this code splitting docs from react](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html#reactlazy)